# How bind select options in the HTML with two pre-defined values to insert data in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I create an event creator in my admin dashboard, and everything is working ok, but now i need insert a new field:

```
info: Object
```

In my HTML event creator, i have this selection:

```
<label for="info">Information Type:</label>
<select id="info" name="info">
 <option>Normal</option>
 <option>Special</option>
</select>
```

With a post to `/create`

When this event arrive in my controller, i need save all the form inputs in my database, and is fine, this part is 100% working.

But, before make the save, i am using this code to bind the select option with the real value of the field `info` in the database:

```
event.pre('save', function(next) {
 if (this.info === 'Normal') {
   this.info = ['this text', 'is one text, but i want show as a list', 'that's why i am doing this']
 } else if (this.info === 'Special') {
   this.info = ['same', 'happens', 'here']
 }
});
```

I want know if this is right, is working, but for me looks wrong.

So for example, if i choose 'Normal', will appear like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>This text</li>
  <li>is one text, but i want show as a list</li>
  <li>that's why i am doing this</li>
</ul>
```

I want know if the whole thing is right, and if not, how to do it right. I also want alternatives using only HTML if possible, without using the pre save.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `info` field's values are constant I think your solution is the best.

But if you need to use dynamic values for your `info` field you might change your codes as like here;

http://jsfiddle.net/oprz2p2e/

If you have a lot of fields on your form, you can collect your data using jQuery `$("#yourFormId").serialize()` method.

ps: I think you know how to show this data using EJS. You can list `info` field values using forEach together EJS.